# One definition of a force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, definition

So I know there are many questions on this subject here and I know them all but this question is a bit more concrete. So, knowing that it is hard to rigorously define a force, I will quote a definition of a force in a primary school textbook: 
A force is a physical quantity which we use to describe interaction.

So, I am finding it hard to understand why is this written in this way? For me, we can see that a body moves when some other body is near it. It can move or change shape. We can say that there is some interaction going on betwen bodies i.e. we can see that two bodies act on each other because when we remove either one of them there is no more movement. I can see that this interaction has a direction or I can assigne a direction to it by observing the direction of change of velocity. Also, I can quantify it. So, in a way I can say that interaction is measurable and I can call it a force. I dont see the need for distinguishing betwen force and interaction, they seem to be almost the same. Couldnt we just say that force is a cause of change in objects velocity or shape whoes source is some other object?

Comment: You certainly don't want the word "movement" in these definitions, because it will be interpreted as "non-zero velocity" while the thing that force is linked to *acceleration*.

Comment: As i mentioned below said mistake...

Answer (score 3):

Interaction is semantically embodying the idea of action between (inter) two systems. In a way, it is a more general concept than force in contemporary physics.

A way to see the difference is to recall that interactions may change velocities, but they may also change energies. Well, in classical mechanics, potential energy is directly related to forces (force is the gradient of the potential energy). However, in quantum mechanics, the concept of force as a cause of velocity changes disappears, while interaction as a way to control the energy of a  system remains.

There are examples of interaction in classical physics where no force is implied.
A couple of examples could be:

- thermal interaction between a cube of ice and its environment. The process of heating and eventual melting of the ice can be described as an interaction where no force appears. Still, two subsystems (ice and environment) *interact*.
- notwithstanding the interaction of light and solid bodies can hardly be reduced to the introduction of forces (do we introduce forces for describing refraction or diffraction?), there is no doubt that some effect on the light propagation due to the solid body is present.

This is to clarify that, in physics, force and interaction are not always synonyms.
Whether it is worthwhile to pinpoint such a difference with kids 12 o 13 years old is left to who is directly involved with such a teaching.

About a reasonable definition of force for that age, I think starting from the basic properties of forces in mechanics, i.e., as a possible source of deformation or change of velocity, characterized by magnitude and direction, could be enough. In any case, the choice of the definition should be consistent with the planned use of that concept in the teaching.

Comment: I totaly agree with you on every point and of course if we look at QM or QFT we can see that there is still idea of interaction in so called interaction terms in the lagrangian etc. But you can even derive force and explain why it is the way it is, for example yukawa potential which gives you a force. But what is this definition of a force saying and with what I am having problems is choosing to say that force is something that we use to describe interaction. Exactly because we have many types of interactions I would not define the force this way.

Comment: For example, if you just observe you can first see that some force eg a magnetic is acting on a body. After some more investigation you can see that at the same time that body is acting on a magnet. With the force. And THEN you say aha, these bodies are in interaction. But the force is sort of influence that changes speed and shape of a body. So for kids I think its better to go this way. Of course, for me I could say that EM interaction is almost the same as EM force because I am used to thinking in terms of interaction when some one says force. Even Feynmann when teaching basic mechanics

Comment: Says that force is some sort of influence. And that there is third Newtons law. And only then we could cinstruct the idea of interaction.

Answer (score 1):

"I dont see the need for distinguishing betwen force and interaction"

When there is an interaction (involving forces!) between two bodies each experiences a force. The forces are  equal in magnitude but opposite in direction. It is clear that in my last sentence we could not sensibly substitute 'interactions' for 'forces'. There is one interaction but two forces. It is the way we use the words. It's a little bit like having the general term 'human being' to cover both male and female. [I did say a *little* bit ...]

Another aspect of the way we use the words is that although interactions are quantifiable, the actual quantification is done using forces, potentials etc. It's rather like saying that when you connect a battery to a bulb and the bulb lights up, it's because of electricity. When it comes to quantifying, we need the concepts of current and pd.

If we're talking pedagogy, it's usual (in the UK at least) to tell children that a force is a push or a pull. Although this may be derided as empty, circular etc, it points them in the right direction so they tend no longer to make vague statements like "electricity is a force". We then investigate combining forces, and some of the things that forces, and in particular the resultants of forces, do. This takes them beyond *push* and *pull* [though I don't think that $\Sigma F=d(mv)/dt$ is adequate by itself as a definition of force. That's another story.] Then, at some stage, comes Newton's third law about forces between body A and body B (perhaps restricted to local interactions) and the idea that this is not a co-incidence but that the two forces are part of the same *interaction*.

Comment: If one body eg body A acts with some force on body B then body B acts with the same force with oposite sense on body A. Its enough. Right?

Comment: Enough for what? We have two different forces.

Comment: Well if i was trying to explain a force to a kid i would say that force is a sort of influence on a body which causes it to change speed or shape. And that when one body acts on the other the other acts on the first one. In my nind force and interaction are interchangeable

Comment: So to say it better you can not define the force in that way because you are not saying much.

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić They are not exactly interchangeable for the basic reason that interaction is a somewhat abstract and fluid notion which becomes concrete and quantifiable in different ways in different frameworks. In the framework of Newtonian mechanics, the notion of interaction is described using the notion of forces. But, even in Newtonian mechanics, they are not interchangeable because the interaction is something that exists between a pair of particles whereas a force is something that acts on a single particle.

Comment: The full content of the phenomenon of interaction between two particles can be described by describing the forces that one particle exerts on the other. But, a single force acting on one of the particles doesn't contain the full content of the interaction. Especially, in such interactions where Newton's third law is violated, the value of the force exerted on one of the particles because of an interaction between two particles doesn't tell you anything about the value of the force exerted on the other particle because of the same interaction.

Comment: I've added to my answer above.

Comment: @Žarko Tomičić "Well if i was trying to explain a force to a kid i would say that force is a sort of influence on a body which causes it to change speed or shape. And that when one body acts on the other the other acts on the first one. In my mind force and interaction are interchangeable" But it's interesting that you've (wisely) chosen to use the word $force$ twice in your first sentence, rather than the word $interaction$!

Answer (score 0):

Force is a basic concept in physics. You should not expect to be able to define it in a single sentence. The value of your proposed definition depends upon its intended purpose- if you mean it as a way to give a loose idea of force, then it is ok. However, you should bear in mind the following:

1)A force doesn't always result in a change to an object's velocity or shape. if you press against a brick wall neither its velocity or shape need be affected.

2)The source of a force doesn't have to be 'an object'. In the a petrol engine, for example, the piston in a cylinder is forced down by the expansion of the ignited fuel-air mixture, which you wouldn't normally describe as an object.

3) A definition of force ought to cover the fact that forces are vector quantities, that a net force results in an acceleration proportional to the mass of the body upon which the force operates, and that forces are a means of transferring energy.

Comment: Maybe not walls shape but certainly shape of my fingers. I was aiming for a nice simple definition for kids 13 or 12 years age. Mentioned textbook definition seens a bit stupid with its separation of force and interaction.

Comment: Understood. Your objective is laudable- we should find the best possible way to convey the idea of force to kids learning the basics of physics.

Answer (score 0):

Length is what you measure with a ruler, time is what you measure with a clock, and a force is what you measure with a spring scale.  Mass is a more subtle entity.